# Where to put messages in Keycloak extension archive

Tags: java, freemarker, keycloak, properties-file

We've created a Keycloak extension (mainly an additional *Authenticator*) and are trying to package it as a *jar* archive so we can deploy it wihtout having to copy templates and editing `.properties` files.

The authenticator uses a custom form that we've put into the `theme-resources/templates` directory as described in [Theme Resources](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_theme_resource) - and it works nicely. However, we are unable to put the messages into a location where they are picked up. Instead of the message, the message key is displayed. If we put the messages directly into `keycloak-6.0.1/themes/base/login` (instead of into our archive), it works.

It affects two places:

**Localized messages in the custom form** (`company.auth.title` in the below Freemarker template)

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout; section>
    <#if section = "header">
         ${msg("company.auth.title")}
    <#elseif section = "form">
    ...
```

**Error message in the authenticator** (`company.auth.invalid-code`)

```
Response challenge = context.form()
    .setError("company.auth.invalid-code")
    .createForm("company-auth-challenge.ftl");
context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_CREDENTIALS, challenge);
```

The documentation seems to indicate that the localized message files need to go to `theme-resources/resources`, but it's not working.

So where should we put the messages files (such as `messages_en.properties`) in our jar archive so they are picked up by Keycloak?

Comment: This is a very basic requirement for a custom authenticator but the documentation is sketchy and vague.  I'm appalled by this.  "theme-resources/resources/messages" doesn't work either for the record, although it just occurred to me that there might be some caching mechanism at work (wild guess).

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of KeyCloak (as at 6.0.1).  Localization messages are only taken from themes.  You'll have to create your own theme and bundle it with the JAR.  And since KeyCloak does not merge themes you cannot redefine the default *keycloak* theme in your JAR, so you must change the realm's login theme to your custom theme.

Your templates can remain in *theme-resources*, but canonically should reside in the theme's folder parallel to *theme.properties*.  If your theme is called *brokenspoon* then your MVP JAR should contain:

- META-INF/keycloak-themes.json
- theme/brokenspoon/login/messages/messages_en.properties
- theme/brokenspoon/login/theme.properties
- theme-resources/templates/my-custom-login.ftl

**Contents of *keycloak-themes.json*** - Define one theme for login:

```
{
  "themes": [{
    "name" : "brokenspoon",
    "types": [ "login" ]
  }]
}
```

**Contents of *theme.properties*** - 
Your custom theme can extend the default *keycloak* theme:

```
parent=keycloak
```

Deploy your JAR, restart the *Keycloak* server, then change the default theme for the realm under *Realm Settings* → *Themes*.  It's important to restart the server before changing the theme setting but after deploying the JAR because otherwise themes from the JAR are not loaded.  This appears to be due to an internal caching mechanism specific to themes.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Good to have a confirmation and thanks for the helpful instructions.

Comment: Same issue here with keycloak v6.0.1. I already develop Authentication SPI with embed i18n properties but it seems to not work on 6.0.1. It's desired by the Keycloak team or a regression ?

Comment: @Melkior I derived my answer from the source code, it looks like this is by design.